# Alpine js, mouseover to show text, no jumping content

Tags: mouseover, image-gallery, alpine.js

I made an example on CodePen - [CodePen](https://codepen.io/sergiochizhikov/pen/vWgN/)

I want the image to disappear on hover with the mouse and a block with text appears.
My problem is that I don't understand how to remove the jumps if I want to keep the text.
Now there are unpleasant jumps in my layout, which is caused by display: none;.

And I think to add smooth transitions. For reuse, I moved the code to Alpine.data. Is this a good idea?
I've used alpine before with tilewind and it's easier. But in this bootstrap project, there are complications.

Please tell me what are your ideas?
Thanks in advance!

```html
<div class="container advantage-pic">

  <div class="pic1" x-data="onHover" @mouseover="visible" @mouseleave="novisible">
    <img class="pic" x-show="!open" src="https://napli.ru/advantage-pic1.png" alt="">
    <div class="txt" x-cloak x-show="open" >Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pic2" x-data="onHover" @mouseover="visible" @mouseleave="novisible">
    <img class="pic" x-show="!open" src="https://napli.ru/advantage-pic2.png" alt="">
    <div class="txt" x-cloak x-show="open">Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pic3" x-data="onHover" @mouseover="visible" @mouseleave="novisible">
    <img class="pic" x-show="!open" src="https://napli.ru/advantage-pic3.png" alt="">
    <div class="txt" x-cloak x-show="open">Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="pic4" x-data="onHover" @mouseover="visible" @mouseleave="novisible">
    <img class="pic" x-show="!open" src="https://napli.ru/advantage-pic4.png" alt="">
    <div class="txt" x-cloak x-show="open">Some text</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```css
[x-cloak] {
    display: none !important;
}

.advantage-pic {
  max-width: 760px;
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-column-gap: 12px;
    grid-row-gap: 12px;
  
}

.pic1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.pic2 {
    grid-area: 1 / 2 / 2 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.pic3 {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 3 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.pic4 {
    grid-area: 3 / 1 / 4 / 3;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}


.txt {
    color: blue;
    background: #fe980f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transition: height 500ms ease 0s;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    }

.pic {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
  
}
```

```js
import Alpine from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/alpinejs@3.10.5";

Alpine.data("onHover", () => ({
    open: false,

    visible() {
        this.open = true;
        },

    novisible() {
        this.open = false;
    },
}));

queueMicrotask(() => {
    Alpine.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved! There was no need to hide the picture, there was no jump!

```
x-show="!open"
```